# nth number that is divisible by the square of the sum of its digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I want to find an n number that is divisible by the square of the sum of its digits, and I have the following program code:

```
def f(n):
    return sum(list(map(int, str(n))))

def check(n):
    return n % f(n)**2 == 0

def get(n):
    s = i = 0
    
    while s < n:
        i += 1
        if check(i):
            s += 1

    return i


n = int(input())
print(get(n))
```

However, this code is slow for large numbers, what would be the optimal solution. That is, how to speed up this code by 2-3 times?

Comment: For example 162 % (1+6+2)^2 = 0

Comment: Ask on Code Review, as it is working.

Comment: Your question is clear enough, however for optimal clarity I would write "divisible by the square of the sum of its **digits**".

Answer (score 1):

- Mathematicians might have a better algo.
- Consider storing the results in a file so you don't have to start
  from 0 every time.
- Tiny optimisation:
  check if N is divisible by f(n) first. If that check fails, N cannot be
  divisible by f(n)*f(n) and you don't have to square the f(n) value.

  ```
  def check(n):
       fn = f(n)
       d, m = divmod(n, fn)
       return m == 0 and d % fn == 0
  ```
- a better optimisation:
  don't sum the digits by converting int->str->int

  ```
  def f(n):
      s = 0 
      while n:
          n, m = divmod(n, 10) 
          s += m
      return s
  ```

  UPDATE: even quicker with a cache:

  ```
  from functools import cache

  @cache
  def f(n):
      if n == 0:
          return 0
      n, m = divmod(n, 10)
      return m + f(n)
  ```

With these small modifications the program runs on my PC about 55% faster (not exactly measured, after UPDATE).

Comment: Using ints in place of strings, with a very similar implementation, took me a bit more than half of the time per iteration in Colab (measured with timeit for a 5 digit number)

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I tried too, see the UPDATE.